# MediaElements.js YouTube audio autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, youtube

I am using mediaelements.js to play audio. My problem is, that the autoplay function is not working. Please help me to solve this problem. When I change the `type="audio/youtube"` to `type="audio/mp3"` autoplay is working, but not in YouTube.

My code:

```
<script src="../build/jquery.js"></script>  
<script src="../build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../build/mediaelementplayer.min.css" />
</head><body>

<audio id="audio-player" 
    src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzGKsXPBILw"  
    type="audio/youtube" controls="controls" 
    autoplay="true"/></audio>

<script>
    $('audio').mediaelementplayer();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
var v = $('audio');
new MediaElement(v, {success: function(media) {
    media.play();
}});
</script>
```

Firstly get the instance of audio element and then apply play once media element is added.

You can refer [here](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement) for further information